# Is there a concise English translation of the Russian word and concept samochuvstvie?

Tags: phrase-requests

I am rereading accounts of the [1996 climbing disaster on Everest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1996_Mount_Everest_disaster).  Two books by Anatoli Boukreev, *The Climb* and *Above the Clouds* put emphasis on a climber's ***samochuvstvie***.

> Above 5,000 meters the participants' good form was reassuring.  They
>   had a fighting spirit and, from their external appearances, didn't
>   look as if they had any serious problems with their health or
>   *samochuvstvie*.

The translator says this word has no equivalent in English, and explains it as:

> A Russian concept. An impression of a person's state of being, the
>   combined and observable aspects of a person's mental, physical and
>   emotional state.  (*The Climb*, Chapter 6, Doing the Details)

A Google search pulls up an entry from [Bab.la Russian-English Dictionary](https://en.bab.la/dictionary/russian-english/%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5)

> general condition

This may be the best one can do for a concise translation, but it doesn't adequately describe what an Everest guide is looking for in a wanna-be Everest climber.

I'm **not** looking for a single word, but a concise translation that captures the spirit of the Russian. If the translator's note is as concise as it gets, that is an answer.  Please note: this Q is purely curiosity-driven; I'm not looking for a free translation service.

Comment: It seems to me that the first quote you gave is a good explanation of the word. Are you asking to have that sentence restated in some way?

Comment: @Jason Bassford I wonder if there is a more concise definition.  I know words don't map one to one between languages, but there is a big difference between one word and a longish sentence. Every time I read that "translation", I get an itch.

Comment: *Holistic state*? That sounds a lot more like the longer version than does *general condition*.

Comment: I'd like to see the word samochuvstvie in the sentence in order to understand the context better. Sometimes the word can translate as "well-being" and "general condition" (obshee samochuvstvie), but it means literally the way one feels.

Comment: @Enguroo See new second paragraph

Comment: I'd say that in this particular sentence we can do without "or samochuvstvie" because there is the "problems with their health" part. So, "samochuvstvie" seems unnecessary. Perhaps, the writer uses it to add some Russian feel. Anyway, "samochuvstvie" is always used to talk about one's health. So don't assume it should mean something like stamina, which an Everest guide might be looking for in a climber.

Comment: @Enguroo The writer is a Russian, and when one reads the entire book, it is clear he is looking for more than health in his clients.  He is looking for grit, perseverance and common sense (all my terms) and whatever makes some people do well at high altitude, which is more than health.  Possibly high altitude mountaineers use the word in their own peculiar way.

Comment: I would be inclined to use something like "physical readiness" in a situation like the Mt Everest climb, where the objective is clearly defined and the participants' health is being gauged  (rather specifically) in terms of how well prepared they are physically to undertake the remaining stages of the challenge. If you needed to include a psychological dimension, you could say "morale and physical readiness."

Comment: I'm sure that a guide is looking for all of those things (perseverance, common sense, etc.), but the problem is "samochuvstvie" doesn't mean any of them. Of course, when we read the entire book, we understand what is meant. But when I (a native Russian speaker) read that sentence in your question, I only think of physical stuff. Sorry.

Comment: Come to think of it, perhaps, we can contrast "serious problems with their health" with "samochuvstvie". The latter means  the way one feels at a particular moment in time, while health problems may be constant.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be best suited for a Russian language site.

Comment: @Enguroo In another place, Boukreev says: For some reason, I had no desire to begin that undertaking. Missing was my usual presummit high, when every muscle and nerve is ready for work, ready to face the hard, wearisome struggle. My internal voice was quiet. I wondered how to interpret that. Was it poor samochuvstvie, illness, or lack of preparation? I recalled similar internal states on other occasions: times in bad
weather when I had had no desire or motivation to venture out, moments when my intuition about some change in conditions had
stopped me.

Comment: Thank you for this new sentence. So, the author says "poor samochuvstvie" and then adds "illness". It's all perfectly logical to me. Feeling bad doesn't necessarily mean you are ill. Remember the translator's explanation "it's the combined and observable aspects of a person's mental, physical and emotional state". So, maybe the climber is anxious, emotionally disturbed or something, but that inevitably leads to some physical symptoms. It's all about poor samochuvstvie.

Comment: @KarlG- Not sure that asking "What's the best English translation of '*samochuvstvie*' on the Russian site makes any sense.  We'd certainly close a question here that asks, "What's the best Russian translation of '*tubular*'."

Answer (score 2):

The word *самочувствие* (transliterated here as 'samochuvstvie') has a simple sense and literally it's 'feeling yourself' (sam = self, 'o' is a linking letter, 'chuvstv' is a root of words like 'feeling' or 'to feel', and 'ie' is an ending making the whole word a *noun*). So it is just about how a person feels (good and healthy or sick). 'What's your [samochuvstvie]?' (how do you feel?) is a typical question a doctor asks after a patient gets some treatment. 'Samochuvstvie' can be literally '**good**' or '**bad**' if not described specifically by that person.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know Russian,
but, just looking at it as a fill-in-the-blank puzzle (in English),
I believe that “morale” fits. 
Or “the state of being psyched [up]” in the sense of
“[put into] the right psychological frame of mind”
([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=psych)),
“to prepare [oneself] psychologically”
([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/psych_1)),
“mentally ready for something”
([Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/psych)),
or “Mentally prepare (someone) for a testing task or occasion”
([ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/psych)).

Answer (score -1):

You might try "***ready, willing, and able***"

[Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ready%2C+willing%2C+and+able)<sup>1</sup> describes is as:

> A phrase used to describe someone who is capable of and eager to do something. *Our team is ready, willing, and able, boss—we just need the order to start production. The senator has inspired a huge number of volunteers who are ready, willing, and able to campaign for her presidential election bid.*

and [The American Heritage Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/ready%2C+willing%2C+and+able)<sup>2</sup> as:

> Well prepared and eager to do something, as in *Any time you want me to babysit, I'm ready, willing, and able.*

---

<sup>1 <sub>Farlex Dictionary of Idioms. © 2015 Farlex, Inc, all rights reserved.</sub></sup> 
<sup>2 <sub>The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer. Copyright © 2003, 1997 by The Christine Ammer 1992 Trust. Published by Houghton Mifflin Harcourt Publishing Company. All rights reserved.</sub></sup>